# 'name not defined' when setting a class to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, default-arguments

Sorry for the dumb question, I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I'm trying to convert my class into a variable but it gives me an error

```
NameError: name 'period' is not defined
```

```
class Stuff():
    
    def __init__(self, period = 1, division = 1): 
    
        print(str(period), str(division))
            
stuff = Stuff(period, division)
```

But I don't understand why it's not defined as I went out of my way to define it as '1' just to be sure.

I get the same error if I don't define the parameters

```
class Stuff():
    
    def __init__(self, period, division): 
    
        print(str(period), str(division))
            
stuff = Stuff()
```

I don't want to define the parameters before I call them as the parameters won't have a value until then.
Nor do I understand why it needs to be defined because function initiation parameters are not literal.

Comment: If you want to call `Stuff` with the default arguments, you want `stuff = Stuff()`

Comment: If I do that without defining the parameters I get the same error.
However, the parameters will not have values until I call them and fill them in, as I would with a normal function. So I cannot define them.

Comment: You *want* the default values in the `def __init__()` line if you want to be able to instantiate the class without explicit parameters.  You *don't want* the values in the `Stuff()` call if you want to use those default values.

Comment: Either you want to call Stuff() and use the default values for arguments, in which case the method must *have* default values for its arguments; or you want to provide the values for those arguments when you instantiate the class, in which case you must *actually provide values*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

Firstly, you're not "converting" your class into a variable. You're instantiating type and assigning that instance to a variable, something that holds a reference to an object.

Moving to the problem at hand. As the comments suggest and extending on that, you're fundamentally misunderstanding default parameters and instantiation.

In your first example you have `period` and `division` parameters which are both defined within the scope of the constructor (`__init__`). It is valid to use these in the constructor because *they exist* in that scope.

Below this you attempt to instantiate `Stuff` by passing variables called `period` and `division` which *do not exist*. They do not exist because you are [outside of the scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) of the constructor.

You need to create these

```py
class Stuff():
    
    def __init__(self, period = 1, division = 1): 
        print(str(period), str(division))


period = 1
division = 1

stuff = Stuff(period, division)
```

The defined variables have nothing to do with the parameters of the `Stuff` class, other than the fact that they are passed in when instantiating this object.

In your second example you've removed these non-existent variables from the instantiation which is correct but you've also removed the default assignment of the parameters in the `Stuff` class which is wrong. It's wrong because now you're instantiating an object whose constructor has required parameters, without this it does not know what to do with those parameters.

The error reflects this mandatory requirement

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'period' and 'division'
```

For the second example, the correct syntax would be

```py
class Stuff():
    
    def __init__(self, period = 1, division = 1):
        print(str(period), str(division))


stuff = Stuff()
```